# VBA code in Outlook for extracting Excel attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to download all the xlsx extension files into a folder from unread emails in my inbox and mark those emails as read and also give a unique naming convention based on time stamps.

Until now all I have achieved is to modify a code I found online

```
Sub GetAttachments()
' This Outlook macro checks a the Outlook Inbox for messages
' with attached files (of any type) and saves them to disk.
' NOTE: make sure the specified save folder exists before
' running the macro.
    On Error GoTo GetAttachments_err
' Declare variables
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    i = 0
' Check Inbox for messages and exit of none found
    If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
               "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
' Check each message for attachments
    For Each Item In Inbox.Items
' Save any attachments found
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments

    If Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = "xlsx" Then
            ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
                FileName = "C:\Users\vduraiswamy\Desktop\attachments\" & _
                    Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                End If
                Next Atmt
    Next Item
' Check filename of each attachment and save if it has "xls" extension
            i = i + 1
' Show summary message
    If i > 0 Then
        MsgBox "I found " & i & " attached files." _
        & vbCrLf & "I have saved them into the C:\Users\vduraiswamy\Desktop\attachments." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Have a nice day.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If
' Clear memory
GetAttachments_exit:
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub
' Handle errors
GetAttachments_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
        & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume GetAttachments_exit
End Sub
```

The code is giving an error which says "unable to perform this action on this type of attachment" midway after downloading a couple of files.

I would also like the code to look into just unread emails.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub GetAttachments()
' This Outlook macro checks a the Outlook Inbox for messages
' with attached files (of any type) and saves them to disk.
' NOTE: make sure the specified save folder exists before
' running the macro.
    On Error GoTo GetAttachments_err
' Declare variables
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    i = 0
' Check Inbox for messages and exit of none found
    If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
               "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
' Check each message for attachments
    For Each Item In Inbox.Items
        If Item.UnRead = True Then 'Add this for checking unread emails
            ' Save any attachments found
                    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                        If (Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = "xlsx") Or (Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = ".xls") Then
                        ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
                            FileName = "C:\Documents and Settings\epadillo\Desktop\test\" & _
                                Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
                            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                            Item.UnRead = False 'Mark email item as read
                            i = i + 1
                        End If
                Next Atmt
        End If
    Next Item

' Show summary message
    If i > 0 Then
        MsgBox "I found " & i & " attached files." _
        & vbCrLf & "I have saved them into the C:\Users\vduraiswamy\Desktop\attachments." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Have a nice day.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If
' Clear memory
GetAttachments_exit:
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub
' Handle errors
GetAttachments_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
        & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume GetAttachments_exit
End Sub
```

Comment: VJ - Please try this code. this will download xlsx or xls attachments coming from unread emails and when downloading is complete, it will mark the email item as read. HOpe this helps....

Comment: OHWW

It is brilliant!Thanks a lot , I have been sweating with this for ever .

I was also wondering if I would be able to rename the files based on the time during which the mail was sent rather than based of creation time in the looop below

For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments If (Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = "xlsx") Or (Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = ".xls") Then ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary. FileName = "C:\Documents and Settings\epadillo\Desktop\test\" & _ Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName

Comment: if you want to use the time when the email was received, please replace Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") with this one Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_").....

Answer (score 0):

Try bypassing attachments that are not documents.

```
        End If
nonvalidAttachment:
    Next Atmt
Next Item
```

Normally you would work with the number but here the number is not constant but the description is constant.

```
GetAttachments_err:

If Err.Description = "Outlook cannot perform this action on this type of attachment." Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume nonvalidAttachment
End if

MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
        & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error!"
Resume GetAttachments_exit
```